# Send and receive data from a websocket server using sockets in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sockets, websocket

i am new to network programming and would really appreciate your help to receive and send data to a server.  I am trying to Use Sockets to Send and Receive data from a server which is developed using WebSockets.

Until now i have created the following Code which i think is wrong: in this code i am trying to send data on a normal thread but receive data on a different thread so that the program dont go on hold.

as i send data to the server, after some time i get this text reply on the textbox in which i am trying to receive the server response:

> HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented

Any help will be much appreciated

**TCPControl class(handles the connection, send and receive matters)**

```
Public Class TCPControl

Public client As TcpClient
Public DataStream As StreamWriter

Private ReceiveData As StreamReader

Private comThread As Thread
Public isListening As Boolean = True

Public Event MessageReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)

Public Sub New(Host As String, Port As Integer)

    Try
        client = New TcpClient(Host, Port)
        DataStream = New StreamWriter(client.GetStream)

        comThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        comThread.Start()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub Listening()

    Do Until isListening = False

        If client.Connected = True Then
            ReceiveData = New StreamReader(client.GetStream)
        End If

        Try
            RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, ReceiveData.ReadLine)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        Thread.Sleep(10)
    Loop

End Sub

Public Sub Send(Data As String)
    DataStream.Write(Data & vbCrLf)
    DataStream.Flush()
End Sub End Class
```

**Form1 class(handles form load and other stuff)**

```
Public Class Form1

Private client As TCPControl
' Private receiveClient As TCPControlReceive

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' client = New TCPControl("174.129.224.73", 80)
    client = New TCPControl(GetIpAddress("echo.websocket.org").ToString, 80)
    If client.client.Connected Then Label1.Text = "Connected"

    'receiveClient = New TCPControlReceive
    AddHandler client.MessageReceived, AddressOf OnLineReceived

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub UpdateMessageDelegate(TB As TextBox, txt As String)

Private Sub UpdateText(TB As TextBox, txt As String)
    If TB.InvokeRequired Then
        TB.Invoke(New UpdateMessageDelegate(AddressOf UpdateText), New Object() {TB, txt})
    Else
        If txt IsNot Nothing Then
            TB.AppendText(txt & vbCrLf)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnLineReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)

    UpdateText(txtReceive, Data)

End Sub

Private Function GetIpAddress(address As String) As IPAddress

    Dim ips As IPAddress()
    ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(address)
    Return ips(0)
End Function

Private Sub SendMessage()
    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        client.Send(txtSend.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_ContextMenuStripChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ContextMenuStripChanged
    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        client.DataStream.Close()
        client.Client.Close()
    End If
    client.isListening = False

End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    SendMessage()
    txtSend.Clear()
End Sub      End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented' was sent by the server, not generated by VB.

I would assume from this that your code works fine, and the problem lies with the command(s) you are sending after the client connects.

Comment: the server is supposed to send back any text that i send it. but it sent me this instead

Comment: You need to send a command to a server upon connection, what are you trying to do? If you want a page, send `GET /path` after the client connects. Else nothing will happen, the server will just timeout.

Comment: Ok, I see now, it just 'echoes' what you send to it, correct? Maybe you have to send `ECHO` or something before your text. Not implemented seems to suggest you have your syntax wrong.